# Restore bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a backup directory with a tar file in that directory (/home/username/userhome/backup/userbackup-${currentdate}.tar.gz).
I would like a create a script that:

1. creates the restore directory if it does not exist
2. displays the contents of the backup directory containing tar files of previous backups
3. asks the user to enter the name of the tar file to restore
4. uses the tar command to restore the file to the new restore directory and log file

So far my script has

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir restore -p
ls /home/username/userhome/backup
echo "Enter the file name to be restored"
read $filename
tar xvf "/home/username/userhome/restore/$filename" &>/home/username/userhome/restore/restore.log
```

I am a complete newbie so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Suggest you change to the directory first. `mkdir -p restore` will create the `restore` directory in whatever directory is the current directory when the script is called. Also suggest `mkdir -p restore || exit 1` so you exit at that point if you don't have permissions to create the directory. When you `cd` to the directory holding the `.tar.gz` files, suggest you use `select choice in *.tar.gz; do ... done` . The `select` command will create a menu for you to select a file from. It will display a numbered list and you choose the number next to the filename you want, `choice` holds the name.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from the comment, one thing you always want to do when writing a script is to validate each step along the way. For instance, if you cannot create the new `restore` directory, you don't want to loop and then attempt to extract a tar.gz file to the directory that doesn't exits.

Virtually all commands return `0` on success or a nonzero error on failure. You can use this to your advantage to check if the command succeeded and if it didn't you simply exit. A quick way to do that is:

```
command || exit 1
```

In your case creating the `restore` directory that could be:

```
mkdir -p restore || exit 1
```

You can add additional error messages if you like, but most time the error generated by the failure will be sufficient to tell you what went wrong.

Whenever you are operating on a fixed base directory using subdirectories of that base, it is best to create a variable for that base directory you can use in your script. For example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

userdir="${1:-/home/username/userhome}"
budir="$userdir"/backup
restore="$userdir"/restore
```

Here `userdir` is the base directory and you have additional variables for the backup directory and restore directory. This makes it convenient to reference or operate on files in any of the directories. Note also how `userdir` can be set from the first command line argument or uses `/home/username/userhome` by default if no argument is given.

You can create `restore` and change to that directory, validating each step as follows:

```sh
mkdir -p restore || exit 1
cd "$restore" || exit 1
```

For the menu, let `select` create the menu for you (now if you have hundreds of `.tar.gz` files, you may need to write a custom pager, but for a few dozen files, `select` will be fine). You can generate the menu and restore the selected file with:

```sh
select choice in "$budir"/*.tar.gz; do
  tar -xvf "$choice" &>"$restore/restore.log"
  break
done
```

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

userdir="${1:-/home/username/userhome}"
budir="$userdir"/backup
restore="$userdir"/restore

mkdir -p restore || exit 1
cd "$restore" || exit 1

select choice in "$budir"/*.tar.gz; do
  tar -xvf "$choice" &>"$restore/restore.log"
  break
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

Say I have a couple of `.tar.gz` files in a directory, e.g.

```
$ tree /home/david/tmpd/backup
backup
├── v.tar.gz
└── x.tar.gz
```

Then to create a restore directory under the `tmpd` directory I can run the script as:

```
$ bash ~/scr/tmp/restore.sh /home/david/tmpd
1) /home/david/tmpd/backup/v.tar.gz
2) /home/david/tmpd/backup/x.tar.gz
#? 2
```

By choosing `2` above the `x.tar.gz` file is restored under the `restore` directory, e.g.

```
$ ls -al restore/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 david david 80 Oct 29 01:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 david david 80 Oct 29 01:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 david david 60 Oct 29 01:00 home
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 57 Oct 29 01:00 restore.log
```

So the `restore` directory was successfully created, the `restore.log` was created and the `.tar.gz` file was restored under the `restore` directory.

The contents of `restore.log` are

```
$ cat restore/restore.log
home/david/scr/utl/xscrd.sh
home/david/scr/utl/xzdate.sh
```

(which were the two sample files I added to the `x.tar.gz` file)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: That is fantastic, David. I very much appreciate you taking the time to answer my question in such detail, just the help I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your scripting!